# UICollectionViewCells do not resize when the UICollectionView do

Tags: ios, ipad, uicollectionview

I am creating an interface for iPad with an UICollectioView and autolayout. The UICollectioView has leading and trailing to the superview constraints and I have an animation who makes it smaller horizontally.

The footer and the header of the sections resize with this animation but the cells of the collection view do not.

Do someone has the same problem?

Thanks

Comment: i think you should set autolayout-constraints to cell also.

Comment: Hi @santhu. It has to. I have tried to put all the stuff of the UICollectionViewCell inside of one view (all with autolayout) and it still does not work :(

Comment: try to call layoutSubViews explicitly from collectionView.